# VBA Needed For Moving Multiple Rows From One Sheet To Another Using Multiple Values and Multiple Columns, In a Specific Order

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up a macro for a report to show which managers sheets have which rows from a master sheet. I found a basic macros that will work but it only uses one value and one column. I am trying to tweak it to pull from 3 specific columns, in a specific order, as the managers are identified by 3 different columns. I have 4 sheets:

"Master", "Manager1", "Manager2", "Manager3"

While I want the entire row copied, it needs to be based on specific data in each of the three columns.

Manager1 is only G"1",H"2",I"3" or G"2",H"5",I"8"

Manager2 is only G"2",H"3",I"9" or G"3",H"5",I"9"

Manager3 is only G"1",H"5",I"9" or G"3",H"4",I"5"

And it needs to be in that order, G, then H, then I.

I have the code below but it is giving me range errors and object required errors.

```
Sub CopyYes()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim t As Range
    Dim wsMas As Worksheet
    Dim wsMan1 As Worksheet
    Dim wsMan2 As Worksheet
    Dim wsMan3 As Worksheet

Set wsMas = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
Set wsMan1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Manager1")
Set wsMan2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Manager2")
Set wsMan3 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Manager3")

With wsMas
    Set r = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
End With

    i = 1
    For Each r In Source.Range("G1", "I100")
        If r = "1" Then
            Set r = Source.Range("H1:H100")
                If r = "2" Then
                    Set r = Source.Range("I1:I100")
                        If r = "3" Then
                            Set Target = wsMan1
                                Source.Rows(r.Row).Copy Target.Rows(i)
                                i = i + 1
                                End If
                    End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

If done correctly, all rows with G being 1, H being 2, and I being 3 should copy over to Manager1's sheet, if not, it will go down the code to see which manager it does go to.

What did I do wrong? If I have to change the code, what would work best for this?

Comment: If you post some sample data, it’d be easier for people here to help you

Comment: The variable `Source` is not defined. That is why you are getting object required errors

Comment: @Sam unless `Source` is the CodeName of a sheet...

Comment: Remove the `.Select` from `Set r = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select`

Comment: Are the cells really strings that look like numbers?  Note the `"1" ` is not equal to `1`.

Comment: Note that changing `r` inside the `For Each r ` will likely cause you huge problems.

Comment: Let's say that `r` equals `Range("A5")`.  When you say `For each r` it does not make sense because `Range("A5")` would not be in any of those other ranges.  When you want to use `r` as a cell in a collection of cells in a range, then you say `For each r`, but you do not set `r`.